# Sum of item in laravel object item with many levels

Tags: php, laravel

I want to take an item called `vote_count` and sum them all up to see the total of voters. The object is quite large, I'll remove what is not relevant and leave only the important part.

```
{ 
   "id":1,
   "name":"Evaluacion al docente por parte de los estudiantes",
   "description":"Evaluacion al docente de la clase de Electronica 1 de la carrera de Ingenieria",
   "user_id":1,
   "anonymous":0,
   "created_at":"2019-12-09 10:30:50",
   "updated_at":"2019-12-10 08:43:40",
   "result":[ 
      { 
         "id":1,
         "type":1,
         "rank":null,
         "title":"Cual es su opinion acerca de la oficina de telematica",
         "options":{ 
            "1":{ 
               "title":"answer question 1",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "7":{ 
               "title":"answer question 1",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "13":{ 
               "title":"answer question 1",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "19":{ 
               "title":"answer question 1",
               "vote_count":null
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         "id":2,
         "type":2,
         "rank":null,
         "title":"elija 3 opciones",
         "options":{ 
            "1":{ 
               "title":"opcion a",
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "2":{ 
               "title":"opcion b",
               "vote_count":0
            },
            "3":{ 
               "title":"opcion c",
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "4":{ 
               "title":"opcion d",
               "vote_count":2
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         "id":5,
         "type":1,
         "rank":null,
         "title":"texto aslkfjasd asd afsdf",
         "options":{ 
            "3":{ 
               "title":"jdflaksfj alkdfj ajfawieur alk jaklf",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "9":{ 
               "title":"sdf asd ads",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "15":{ 
               "title":"sdfa sd fasdfads a",
               "vote_count":null
            },
            "21":{ 
               "title":"asdfasd",
               "vote_count":null
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         "id":3,
         "type":4,
         "rank":null,
         "title":"bota la basura en los basureros?",
         "options":{ 
            "1":{ 
               "title":"No",
               "vote_count":2
            },
            "2":{ 
               "title":"Si",
               "vote_count":1
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         "id":4,
         "type":3,
         "rank":6,
         "title":"Que calificacion le daria a la limpieza general de la universidad?",
         "options":{ 
            "1":{ 
               "title":1,
               "vote_count":0
            },
            "2":{ 
               "title":2,
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "3":{ 
               "title":3,
               "vote_count":0
            },
            "4":{ 
               "title":4,
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "5":{ 
               "title":5,
               "vote_count":0
            },
            "6":{ 
               "title":6,
               "vote_count":1
            }
         }
      },
      { 
         "id":6,
         "type":3,
         "rank":3,
         "title":"jaksjakjf fjf a jaskj fkf ja range",
         "options":{ 
            "1":{ 
               "title":1,
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "2":{ 
               "title":2,
               "vote_count":1
            },
            "3":{ 
               "title":3,
               "vote_count":1
            }
         }
      }
   ],

   //rest of it, that is not relevant
}
```

As you can see it's questions and the options that people chose what I'm trying to count in order to later on show the % of people that picked a question option instead of the # amount, since some of the questions are optional I have to calculate the total for each question instead of the whole survey. This is how I'm saving the data in the controller I'll remove the Text type question saving part because the total is not needed for that type of question

```
$survey = Survey::with('surveyQuestions.responseType',
            'surveyQuestions.surveyQuestionOption', 'surveyQuestions.answer')
            ->where('id', $id)->first();

$result = [];

foreach ($survey['surveyQuestions'] as $question) {
    $options = [];

    //multiple choice
    if ($question->response_type_id === 2)  {
        foreach ($question['surveyQuestionOption'] as $option) {
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($survey['answer'] as $answer) {
                if ($answer->survey_question_id === $option->survey_question_id
                        && (int)$answer->answer === $option->id) {
                    $count++;
                }

                $options[$option->id] = [
                    'title' => $option->option,
                    'vote_count' => $count
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    //ranking
    if ($question->response_type_id === 3) {
        if ($question->rank === 3){
            $question->opciones = [
                ['id' => 1, 'option' => 1],
                ['id' => 2, 'option' => 2],
                ['id' => 3, 'option' => 3]
            ];
        } else if ($question->rank === 4){
            $question->opciones = [
                ['id' => 1, 'option' => 1],
                ['id' => 2, 'option' => 2],
                ['id' => 3, 'option' => 3],
                ['id' => 4, 'option' => 4]
            ];
        } else if ($question->rank === 5){
            $question->opciones = [
                ['id' => 1, 'option' => 1],
                ['id' => 2, 'option' => 2],
                ['id' => 3, 'option' => 3],
                ['id' => 4, 'option' => 4],
                ['id' => 5, 'option' => 5]
            ];
        } else {
            $question->opciones = [
                ['id' => 1, 'option' => 1],
                ['id' => 2, 'option' => 2],
                ['id' => 3, 'option' => 3],
                ['id' => 4, 'option' => 4],
                ['id' => 5, 'option' => 5],
                ['id' => 6, 'option' => 6]
            ];
        }

        foreach ($question['opciones'] as $opt) {
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($question['answer'] as $answer) {
                if ($answer->survey_question_id === $question->id && (int)$answer->answer === $opt['option']) {
                    $count++;
                }

                $options[$opt['id']] = [
                    'title' => $opt['option'],
                    'vote_count' => $count
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    //yes or no
    if ($question->response_type_id === 4) {
        $question->opciones = [
            ['id' => 1, 'option' => 'No'],
            ['id' => 2, 'option' => 'Si']
        ];

        foreach ($question['opciones'] as $opt) {
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($question['answer'] as $answer) {
                if ($answer->survey_question_id === $question->id && $answer->answer === $opt['option']) {
                    $count++;
                }

                $options[$opt['id']] = [
                    'title' => $opt['option'],
                    'vote_count' => $count
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    $result[] = [
        'id' => $question->id,
        'type' => $question->response_type_id,
        'rank' => $question->rank,
        'title' => $question->question,
        'options' => $options
    ];
}
```

I'm really not sure where or how I would calculate the total, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you storing this in a database like mysql?

Comment: @elijah7 yes, right now it's local though

Answer (score 0):

You can search an array "in-depth" by using a recursive array iterator.

See the code below for inspiration:

```php
        $iterator = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array);
        $recursive = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            $iterator,
            \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        );
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($recursive as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'vote_count') {
                $sum += $value;
            }
        }
```